# Supremum of Partial Sum of Normal Variables

Tags: probability, inequality, normal-distribution

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of independent standard normal distributions. $\alpha,\lambda>1$ is a fixed real numbers. Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, and $f(x) = \sqrt{2x\log(\log(x))}$ (many of the werid setup has to do with other parts of the problem). I would like to show that
$$P((\sup_{\lambda^k\leq j\leq\lambda^{k+1}} S_{j-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor})\geq\alpha f(\lambda^k))\sim_{k\to\infty}2P(S_{\lfloor\lambda\rfloor^{k+1}-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}\geq\alpha f(\lambda^k))$$
Through imitation of Etemadi's inequality, I have shown that
$$P((\sup_{\lambda^k\leq j\leq\lambda^{k+1}} S_{j-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor})\geq\alpha f(\lambda^k))\leq2P(S_{\lfloor\lambda^{k+1}\rfloor-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}\geq\alpha f(\lambda^k))$$
Here is what I did: let
$$A_j=\{\sup_{\lambda^k\leq i<j}S_{j-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}<\alpha f(\lambda^k)\cap S_{j-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}\geq \alpha f(\lambda^k)\}$$
Then there is $$\{\sup_{\lambda^k\leq j\leq\lambda^{k+1}} S_{j-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}\geq\alpha f(\lambda^k)\} = \cup_{\lambda^k\leq j\leq \lambda^{k+1}}A_j$$
And additionally $\{A_j\}$ are disjoint. Thus
\begin{align}
&P((\sup_{\lambda^k\leq j\leq\lambda^{k+1}} S_{j-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor})\geq\alpha f(\lambda^k))\\
&=P(\cup_{\lambda^k\leq j\leq \lambda^{k+1}}A_j)=\sum_{\lambda^k\leq j\leq \lambda^{k+1}}P(A_j)\\
&=P((\cup_{\lambda^k\leq j\leq \lambda^{k+1}}A_j)\cap S_{\lfloor\lambda^{k+1}\rfloor-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}\geq\alpha f(\lambda^k))+P((\cup_{\lambda^k\leq j\leq \lambda^{k+1}}A_j)\cap S_{\lfloor\lambda^{k+1}\rfloor-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}<\alpha f(\lambda^k))\\
&\leq P(S_{\lfloor\lambda^{k+1}\rfloor-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}\geq\alpha f(\lambda^k))+P(\cup_{\lambda^k\leq j\leq \lambda^{k+1}}(A_j\cap S_{\lfloor\lambda^{k+1}\rfloor-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}<\alpha f(\lambda^k)))\\
&\leq P(S_{\lfloor\lambda^{k+1}\rfloor-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}\geq\alpha f(\lambda^k))+P(\cup_{\lambda^k\leq j\leq \lambda^{k+1}}(A_j\cap S_{\lfloor\lambda^{k+1}\rfloor-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}-S_{j-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}<0))\\
&=P(S_{\lfloor\lambda^{k+1}\rfloor-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}\geq\alpha f(\lambda^k))+\sum_{\lambda^k\leq j\leq \lambda^{k+1}}P(A_j)P(S_{\lfloor\lambda^{k+1}\rfloor-j}<0)\\
&=P(S_{\lfloor\lambda^{k+1}\rfloor-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}\geq\alpha f(\lambda^k))+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\lambda^k\leq j\leq \lambda^{k+1}}P(A_j)
\end{align}
This is very similar to the standard proof of Etemadi's inequality, the only difference is that since $S_{j-\lfloor\lambda^k\rfloor}$ is normal, the probability of it being less than $0$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, which gives the last equality. But I don't know how to estimate in the other direction. Any help is appreciated. Many thanks in advance!